# files saves to ntfs drive adhere to umask, ext4 does not

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, linux-mint, chmod, umask

I have 2 storage drives, 1 is NTFS and the other is ext4.

- Both mounted in `/media` as `Storage_1` and `Storage_2`
- I've run `chmod -R *user*:*user* /media/Storage_*`
- I've tried putting `umask=022` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`
- My fstab looks like this:

  ```
  # Entry for /dev/sdc2
  UUID=F88275C4827587C0 /media/Storage_1 ntfs-3g defaults,umask=022,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0

  # Entry for /dev/sdb1
  UUID=b4ef7aaa-97e8-4bdb-bba4-382469b23749 /media/Storage_2 ext4 defaults 0 2
  ```
- I've tried setting `umask=022,uid=1000,gid=1000` on `sdb1`, doesn't work

When I save files to my NTFS drive they adhere to the umask variable (when I download a picture it's given `-rwxr-xr-x`) but when I save files to my ext4 drive they don't (it's given `-rw-r-----`). How do I get my ext4 drive to automatically save files with the same permissions as my NTFS, or will I have to format it to NTFS?

Comment: The shell command is `umask 022` rather than `umask=022`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `umask` option of `mount` is to set visible permissions of every file on the filesystem when the filesystem itself does not support Unix permissions (usually, permissions are stored in the filesystem, when it supports it).

That is why `umask` option of `mount` exists for NTFS (this filesystem does not support Unix permissions), while it has no reason to exit for Ext4 (which does support Unix permissions).

Comment: So if I want to control all my file permissions automatically I have to use ntfs, as umask isn't supported on ext4?

Comment: If you use NTFS (or FAT, for example, or any Unix-permissions unaware filesystem) with proper `umask` option (and maybe `uid` and `gid` if you want to control ownership), the permissions seen from programs on the host will be totally fixed, yes.